# Access denied for user 'abc1234'@'WIN-TQV06J8SPLP' (using password: YES)]

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms, web-config

I am a newbie in hosting a website. This is my first time to upload my project to a hosting site. But im facing an error that I coudnt find any useful solution from Google.

The problem is as below:

I can access other pages of my website, for example: mywebsite.com/login.aspx
But when i access the page that needs to retrieve data from database, I got this.

> Authentication to host 'twinjoin.com' for user 'abc1234' using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user
>   'abc1234'@'WIN-TQV06J8SPLP' (using password: YES)]

Is that possible a hosting company using localhost for the database (MySQL)?
I thought it should be an IP address of the server?

This is how it looks in the phpmyadmin - Database Server information

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.1.73-community - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: abc1234@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Below is my web.config:

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000" />

      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
        </forms>
      </authentication>

      <customErrors mode="Off" />

    </system.web>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="twinjointdbConnectionString" connectionString="Server=mywebsite.com;Database=abc1234_db;Uid=abc1234;Pwd=asd!@#@!" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="home.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories >
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

</configuration>
```

Hope Pros here can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your connection string here is a link for the same .

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

it is mostly not able to read the password field so taking it as blank so your getting password yes .